# $.each() function calling twice in jQuery asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a one dropdownlist which contain all employee names

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.EMP_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.EmployeeList,"== Choose an Employee Name==", new { @id = "ddlemployee" })
```

and I jave text dynamic textboxes like

```
  <table>
   @for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
   {
    <tr> 

 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].SUN_HRS, new { style = "width:50px; height:30px;", @class = "sunhrs" })
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
     @Html.Label("lbl_Sunhrs", new { @id = "lblSunhrs" })

  </td>
  </tr>
   }
 </table>
```

where "ddlemployee" populates all employee names and when select a employee, is goes to controller and get the data and populates data on textboxes like:

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddlemployee").change(function () {
                debugger;
                var startdate = $("#txtStartDate").val();
                var empid = $("#ddlemployee").val();

                location.href = '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDetails", "Employer")?empid=' + empid + '&&projectId=0&&startdate=' + startdate;
                return false;
            });
            $("#btnUpdate").click(function () {
                var empid = $("#ddlemployee").val();
                if (empid != 0) {
                  var msg=  confirm("Are You Sure? Do You Want to Update the Record?");
                  if (msg == false) {
                      alert("You have cancel Updating the record");
                      return false;
                  }
                  else {
                      return true
                  }
                }
                else {

                    alert("Please Select Employee name");
                    return false;
                }
            });

        });

</script>
```

and My problem is, here i want to sum all "sunhrs" of all textboxes values and display on label total value on "lblsunhrs" after getting data based upon employee name,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var total=0;
$('.sunhrs').each(function(){
    total += Number($(this).val());
});
$('.total').text(total);
 });
```

problem is it was calculating same element twice, for example, if populate data as of sunhrs value as '2', getting total as '4', why like this happening , is it DOM effect? is there any alternative solution, for this, for perfect caluclation , please help me.

Comment: Please show your rendered HTML rather than the server-side code.

Comment: How can I? @LeeTaylor

Comment: From your browser. View source. Copy and paste the relevant rendered HTML in your question

Comment: on which event you want to show the sum?